# Connection refused when using YugabyteDB with docker-compose

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m making some tests with YugabyteDB to see what it is capable of and I’m struggling to be able to connect it.

I’m following the [Docker-compose doc](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/docker/docker-compose/#create-a-docker-compose-yaml-file) and got blocked on “Connection refused”:

```
yb-client-n1  | 402762 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.apps.AppBase  - Going to retrieve connection again: Connection to yb-tserver-n1:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried if there was another process using the YSQL port:

```
sudo lsof -i:5433
```

And I couldn’t find any port used but when I start docker-compose, I observed 2 processes on the port 5433 with the name `docker-pr`.

So I started to think it is probably related to my docker environment (Fedora 35) so I checked any issue related to PostgreSQL and I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68702191).

By adding the option `hostname` in docker-compose.yml, it fixed my issue.